# How to create Temporary table in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and need to create temporary table for some purpose. How can I create temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
$createTempTables = DB::unprepared(
                DB::raw("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(
                        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        field_1,
                        field_2,
                        PRIMARY KEY (id)
                )")
            );
```

replace table_name and fields with your table name and fields